# Checking out a tag from SVN using chefs subversion ressource

Tags: svn, chef-infra

I have found [Subversion Ressource](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_subversion.html) in the chef documentation to check out from a subversion repository.

How can I use a subversion ressource to check out a certain tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tag in subversion is just a special location in the repository (usually in /reponame/tags/name_of_your_tag) where a copy of the main development (usually on /reponame/trunk) is stored. You check out a tag in the same way as you check out any other part of a project.

Comment: So it would something like `subversion "example" do repository "http://svn.example.com/example/tags/v0.1.0"; revision "HEAD"; destination cachedir; action :sync; end`?

Comment: That would be my assumption. I've never used chef. Does it work?

Comment: It is just creating an `.svn` at `destination`, not checking out anything. repository I used was `svn://svn.code.sf.net/p/bugs-bug-genie/code/tags/2.1.3` from [BugGenie @ SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bugs-bug-genie/)

Comment: OK, if I use `action :checkout` (only checkout if destination does not exist already) instead it works. Since I am fetching a tag it is OK for me.